# Showing and hiding a div in an li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm aware that this question has been asked and answered a million times but for some reason mine just doesn't work.
I'm want to make the div show on click inside the "li" and it will be hidden until you click on it but it doesn't want to hide the div. I got the function from stackoverflow but it won't work. Here's my code:

HTML:

```
     <div class="small">
    <h2>Bio Technology</h2>
    <br>
    <img src="bio.jpg" id="bioTech" alt="bioTech">
    <ul>
        <li id="bioInfo" class="red">Information
        <div id="bioInfoText">Although biotechnology is a young discipline....</div>
        </li>
        <li id="bioFuture" class="orange">Future</li>
        <li id="bioCont" class="yellow">Content</li>
        <li id="bioAdd" class="brown">Additional</li>
        <li id="bioPrac" class="black">Practical</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here's my JS:

```
       $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#bioInfoText").hide();
    $("#bioInfo").on("click"function(){
        $("#bioInfoText").show();
        });
};
```

I will be forever grateful if some one can help to make it work!

Comment: after event 'click' add `,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way to do it:

By default, if you dont want to display something, keep the `display: none` as inline.

HTML :

```
<div class="small">
    <h2>Bio Technology</h2>
    <br>
    <img src="bio.jpg" id="bioTech" alt="bioTech">
    <ul>
        <li id="bioInfo" class="red">Information
        <div id="bioInfoText" style="display: none;">Although biotechnology is a young discipline....</div>
        </li>
        <li id="bioFuture" class="orange">Future</li>
        <li id="bioCont" class="yellow">Content</li>
        <li id="bioAdd" class="brown">Additional</li>
        <li id="bioPrac" class="black">Practical</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#bioInfo').on('click', function(){
    $('#bioInfoText').toggle();
  });
});
```

I have made it toggable, so that if you click on the #bioInfo again, it will hide again. If you want it to just show, you can replace `toggle()` with `show()`

Check out a [live example here](https://jsfiddle.net/sankalpsingha/xqcjgxa7/).

Comment: Thank you Sankalp, this seems to work on your fiddle so it should work, but for some reason it's not working on my program, I have no idea why, I literally copied it word for word...

Comment: Did you include jquery?

Comment: I did yes, it's in my header.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#bioInfo").on("click", function(){
        $("#bioInfoText").show();
    });
});
```

```css
#bioInfoText{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="small">
    <h2>Bio Technology</h2>
    <br>
    <img src="bio.jpg" id="bioTech" alt="bioTech">
    <ul>
        <li id="bioInfo" class="red">Information
        <div id="bioInfoText">Although biotechnology is a young discipline....</div>
        </li>
        <li id="bioFuture" class="orange">Future</li>
        <li id="bioCont" class="yellow">Content</li>
        <li id="bioAdd" class="brown">Additional</li>
        <li id="bioPrac" class="black">Practical</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div class="small">
<h2>Bio Technology</h2>
<br>
<img src="bio.jpg" id="bioTech" alt="bioTech">
<ul>
    <li id="bioInfo" class="red">Information
    <div id="bioInfoText" style="display: none;">Although biotechnology is a young discipline....</div>
    </li>
    <li id="bioFuture" class="orange">Future</li>
    <li id="bioCont" class="yellow">Content</li>
    <li id="bioAdd" class="brown">Additional</li>
    <li id="bioPrac" class="black">Practical</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#bioInfo').on('click', function(){
$('#bioInfoText').toggle();
});
});
```

This is [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pqrf7gjb/) example

Thanks